# why "tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText() doesn't work and i have to explecitly import it first like "from tkinter import scrolledtext"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm currently reading the book "Python GUI Programming Cookbook" and i programmed this code.

```
import tkinter                                                            #1
from tkinter import scrolledtext                                          #2

win=tkinter.Tk()                                                          #3
src=scrolledtext.ScrolledText(win,width=30,height=4,wrap=tkinter.CHAR)    #4
scr.grid(column=0, columnspan=3)                                          #5
win.mainloop()                                                            #6
```

but the problem is when comment out second line and replace line 4 with:

```
#from tkinter import scrolledtext
src=tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText(win,width=30,height=4,wrap=tkinter.CHAR)
```

python gives me error:

```
AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'scrolledtext'
```

aren't this tow line have the same meaning

Comment: `scrolledtext` is a module of tkinter, it's not living in the main module, so you have to import it explicitely

Comment: can you explain a little. i'm new to this

Comment: In the package [`tkinter`](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Lib/tkinter), there are different modules, like `ttk`, `filedialog` or `scrolledtext`. But they are not loaded by default. When you `import tkinter` it only executes the file [`__init__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py) which loads the main components.

Comment: thanks alot, it solved confusion